# Merging segments

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data with intervals. Columns `Start` and `End`. `Start` always less that `End`. Intervals can be overlapped:

```
Start       |  End
------------+------------
         0  |         209
      1295  |        1569 
      2344  |        2509 
       207  |         858 
      1226  |        1277 
      1283  |        1285 
      1572  |        2338 
      1502  |        3071
```

I need to merge intervals and output in same format

```
    Start   |  End
------------+------------
         0  |         858 
      1295  |        3071 
      1226  |        1277 
      1283  |        1285
```

Initialization code:

```
CREATE TABLE Periods 
(
    [Start] int NOT NULL,
    [End] int  NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Periods ([Start], [End])
SELECT 0, 209
UNION ALL SELECT 1295, 1569
UNION ALL SELECT 2344, 2509
UNION ALL SELECT 207, 858
UNION ALL SELECT 1226,1277
UNION ALL SELECT 1283, 1285
UNION ALL SELECT 1572, 2338
UNION ALL SELECT 1502, 3071
```

Comment: Hi, could you [edit] to explain more clearly the rules for merging? Is it to do with whether ranges overlap each other? Also, you'll get better responses here if you can show an attempt to solve the problem, and where you got stuck with it, so that people don't feel like they're being asked to do your job for you.

Comment: please explain what is your expected output? how doyou want merge your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general form of gaps-and-islands where you can have overlaps.

You can use a cumulative max to get the previous end, and then use that information to calculate "island" starts.  The rest is just aggregation:

```
select min(startp), max(endp)
from (select p.*,
             sum(case when prev_endp >= startp then 0 else 1 end) over (order by startp) as grp
      from (select p.*,
                   max(endp) over (order by startp rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_endp
            from periods p
           ) p
     ) p
group by grp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ae096e0f1dd499941d21319ad38cf908) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I supposed that it should be some classic problem but didn't find solution.

Comment: @Chernikov . . . It is a bit of a twist on the "classic problem".  Or, more specifically, "gaps-and-islands" is a rather wide range of problems with multiple different solutions.